# Can I remove or hide the VIP Folder in Mail on iOS 6?

Tags: email, ios

Is there anyway to remove or hide the new VIP folder in the native Mail app on iOS 6?  I use lots of filters on my Gmail backend and have no use for it.

Comment: Since there isn't a setting to disable it entirely, wouldn't it be great if the software detected us neglecting it with no messages or taps for a week or two and offered to hide / bury it? _I'm not holding my breath, though._

Comment: I, too, find this 'feature' a bit useless as I have Gmail filters, too. You could always give Apple feedback here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html . I gave them a small nudge asking them to remove this as a default and make it an option.

Answer (score 5):

There currently is no way to disable the VIP folder in Mail. The best you can do right now is to move within the Inboxes section of the Mailboxes screen on Mail.

All Inboxes appears pinned to the top position, but each Inbox and the VIP Folder can be arranged in whatever order you please (but not deleted)

To drag the folder

- open Mail
- go to the Mailbox view
- tap on "Edit" and move the folder to where you want it to be among the other Inbox entries.

Perhaps if enough people [give Apple feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) we will be able to suppress VIP entirely or at least move it to below the accounts section in the Mailbox view to bury it at the end of the line.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how it's possible to move the VIP folder down the screen in IOS 6.

Comment: You can only move it down to occupy the last slot of the Inboxes list, not to the very bottom of the Mailboxes window. When you follow the instructions above, three grey lines replace the ">" symbol. Touch-drag the three grey lines & move the VIP Inbox to the bottom.

Comment: Interesting -- when I try this, the arrows (">") disappear, but the drag handles *don't* appear. This is with the iOS 6.0 public release (10A403).

Comment: How many email accounts do you have configured? Maythe the handles only appear if you have more than one.

Comment: FWIW, I have only one.